# rootViewController set in Storyboard not showing on App Launch

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.2, storyboard

I started with an Empty Application and added the storyboard file myself, added a View Controller to the storyboard and then embedded it into the Navigation Controller.  Now, when I launch the app in iOS Simulator - nothing shows.  Screenshot of my storyboard is below.

What needs to happen to get the "AddPerson" to show on launch?

[image]

Update: Yes, Main Storyboard is set, but the Main Interface is blank.  Should that Main Interface be set to something(the drop down is blank)?

Comment: I'm also newbie in this area, but first thing that pop up to my mind, don't you have to do it in on viewdidload on your MasterControllerView?, I started from the template they offer and changing accordingly to my needs (still not getting what I want). As I said I just started and we have very similar problems :)

Comment: Did you set your storyboard as "main storyboard" in the project settings on the "Summary" tab?

Comment: @tarheel thanks for the update (just some days off to relax, and back to work) I'll have a look! And also keep you posted with any update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I searched and searched, and finally found my answer(@jms - hope this answers yours as well). See here: [Xcode 4.2 iOS Empty Application and storyboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906541/xcode-4-2-ios-empty-application-and-storyboards).

Answer (score 29):

Just comment out all your generated code in app delegate's `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method except for `return YES`.

Here's my code and it worked fine.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    //self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    // [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, just select both of them CMD+X to cut, then CMD+V to paste it will set one as root view :)