# implementing custom background on startup - XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am having a problem using the following:

```
....functions
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self.window setBackgroundColor: [self colorWithHexString:@"88C800"]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}....... functions

-(UIColor*)colorWithHexString:(NSString*)hex
{
    NSString *cString = [[hex stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] uppercaseString];

    // String should be 6 or 8 characters
    if ([cString length] < 6) return [UIColor grayColor];

    // strip 0X if it appears
    if ([cString hasPrefix:@"0X"]) cString = [cString substringFromIndex:2];

    if ([cString length] != 6) return  [UIColor grayColor];

    // Separate into r, g, b substrings
    NSRange range;
    range.location = 0;
    range.length = 2;
    NSString *rString = [cString substringWithRange:range];

    range.location = 2;
    NSString *gString = [cString substringWithRange:range];

    range.location = 4;
    NSString *bString = [cString substringWithRange:range];

    // Scan values
    unsigned int r, g, b;
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:rString] scanHexInt:&r];
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:gString] scanHexInt:&g];
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:bString] scanHexInt:&b];

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((float) r / 255.0f)
                           green:((float) g / 255.0f)
                            blue:((float) b / 255.0f)
                           alpha:1.0f];
}
```

I was using an empty project before with this following code and it worked perfect.  When I created a single application and put this within the AppDelegate.m it does not run.  Am I supposed to put this within the viewcontroller.m?

Comment: Are you using storyboard now?

Comment: @BlackFrog Yes I am using the storyboard

Comment: I am new to storyboard myself, but I found this: [When using a storyboard, a main UIWindow is created for you automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906541/xcode-4-2-ios-empty-application-and-storyboards) in the accepted answer.

Comment: No that is not helping